# Iteration in Python throws results no desired

Tags: python, loops, iteration, conditional-statements, enumeration

I am trying to assign payments which are stored in p vector to the vector of debts which is l, so I need to store the dates of payment and the payed value for each date of payment, according the debts.

This code is for the payments for only the first debt ($254.000) (the position 0 in l):[62998, datetime.date(2019, 11, 29), 254000.0]

The desired results are:

1. fechas_rec=[datetime.date(2020, 1, 30), datetime.date(2020, 2, 28)]    vector of payment dates
2. p=[[10000.0, datetime.date(2020, 2, 28)], [110000.0, datetime.date(2020, 3, 30)]] update the payments with the amounts available.
3. recuperados=[137500.0,116500.0] vector of payments according to the vector of the point 1.

But, when update the second last line "recuperados.append()" with the commented code "recuperados.append('a')", the output of the first point change, the question is why?

The new output is:

```
fechas_rec=[datetime.date(2020, 2, 28), datetime.date(2020, 3, 30)]
```

Code:

```
l = [
    [62998, datetime.date(2019, 11, 29), 254000.0],
    [65317, datetime.date(2019, 12, 30), 229000.0],
    [66606, datetime.date(2020, 1, 31), 229000.0],
    [68751, datetime.date(2020, 2, 28), 228000.0],
    [70652, datetime.date(2020, 3, 24), 229000.0],
]

p = [
    [137500.0, datetime.date(2020, 1, 30)],
    [126500.0, datetime.date(2020, 2, 28)],
    [110000.0, datetime.date(2020, 3, 30)],
]


for j in l:
    fechas_rec = []
    recuperados = []
    suma = 0
    for i in enumerate(p):
        suma = suma + i[1][0]
        if suma <= j[2]:
            fechas_rec.append(i[1][1])
            recuperados.append(i[1][0])
        else:
            val = suma - j[2]
            c = i[1]
            del p[: i[0] + 1]
            p.insert(0, [val, c[1]])
            fechas_rec.append(i[1][1])
            recuperados.append()  # recuperados.append('a')
            break
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure where you're getting e.g. `10000.0` in the desired `p` result...

Comment: Deleting and inserting elements in a list you're iterating over is likely to cause elements to be skipped or processed twice.

Comment: I don't believe this, p doesn't present any problem with the change

Comment: For each item you're iterating over, you're erasing the `fechas_rec` list, `recuperados` list, and `suma` variable. Move those out of the `for j in l` loop and see if it works for you

Comment: I have the constrainment break for avoiding an update of these variables

Comment: I tried J. Saw, i can not get the desired output :c

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
l = [
    [62998, datetime.date(2019, 11, 29), 254000.0],
    [65317, datetime.date(2019, 12, 30), 229000.0],
    [66606, datetime.date(2020, 1, 31), 229000.0],
    [68751, datetime.date(2020, 2, 28), 228000.0],
    [70652, datetime.date(2020, 3, 24), 229000.0],
]

p = [
    [137500.0, datetime.date(2020, 1, 30)],
    [126500.0, datetime.date(2020, 2, 28)],
    [110000.0, datetime.date(2020, 3, 30)],
]

for j in l:
    fechas_rec=[]
    recuperados=[]
    suma=0
    for i in enumerate(p):
        suma1=suma
        suma=suma+i[1][0]
        if suma<=j[2]:
            fechas_rec.append(i[1][1])
            recuperados.append(i[1][0])
        else:
            val=suma-j[2]
            c=i[1]
            del p[:i[0]+1]
            p.insert(0,[val,c[1]])
            fechas_rec.append(i[1][1])
            recuperados.append(j[2]-suma1) 
            break  
    drec.append([j[0],fechas_rec,recuperados])    
    sumtot=sumtot+sum(drec[-1][2])
    if sumtot==rectot:
        test=True       
    if test:
        break
```

Comment: Why did you post a new answer instead of editing your original answer?

Comment: I was new in stack and troubles with my pc